# how to check if there is a symbol on a String java

Tags: java

I want to know if is there a method to check if there are any symbols in a string, I know that to check if there's an uppercase is used:

`enter code here`character.isUpperCase(letter);

is there any option such as this but for special symbols like: !@#$%%^"

Comment: Sure: use a regular expression

Comment: that's the only method?

Comment: Alternatively, check if the character is the same as its upper/lowercase equivalent - that is, if upper/lower that you are using also takes the European characters like á and Á.  This includes numbers as non-letters

Comment: No, but it's by far the most sensible if you just need to test for specific characters, or entire character classes.

Answer (score -1):

Take "!@#$%%^" as a string say A
and then run 1 loop i from 0 to less than length of the input string stored in say S and another loop j from 0 to length of A ( j loop is nested within i loop)
now check
if ( S.charAt(i) == A.charAt(j) )
{ // relevant code}

as in:

```
String S= br.readLine();
String A= "!@#$%%^";
for ( int i=0; i< S.length(); i++)
 {for(int j=0;j< A.length(); j++)
    {
      if (S.charAt(i) == A.charAt(j)) 
       {// relevant code
        }
     }
}
```

this brings about the worst case complexity to be O(n²) , but considering the point of view of a school student I view this as the easiest one for academic purposes

Comment: Considering the POV of a school student, I think it’ll be easier to understand if you show rather than tell. Describing code is probably harder than writing it.

Comment: I disagree.  1) Showing them the code just gives them something to copy and paste.  Copy and paste doesn't give knowledge.  2) Explaining in words also means that the reader hones their skills in reading and comprehension.  Both of these things are important for a school student.

Comment: (And example code that is full of bad style is not good either.)